# How can I grab html or javascript code via react from my server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, redux

I want to build something like this inside of my app:

> Whenever a user request for a page load important contents normally,
>   then grab some HTML code from server and display them at the bottom of
>   the loaded page without any refresh at all.

Another thing I want:

> Whenever a user request for a page I want to just load navigation and footer and then grab the main HTML code from my server and display them on the screen without any page refresh and while that runs I want tot display a loading icon.

One more thing I want:

> There is a huge functionality within one of my pages that use javascript code which is 80KB and it take 2 seconds just to load that code. User will probably use that functionality after 3min from the page loaded. (they have to read some contents and do stuff before that), is there a way to load that code without any page refresh while they are reading contents?

I've already know how to grab JSON from server and display them to user using react, what I don't know is how to grab actual code such as HTML or javascript from server using react.

I cannot find any tutorials about that in react topic, should I learn something else to do that? Should I learn **server-side rendering** to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a HTML string from the server and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to insert it into your react component. here is an example for the header and footer example you gave:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      header: 'loading the header',
      footer: 'loading the footer'
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/api/header-and-footer')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({header: res.data.header, footer: res.data.footer})
      });
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='my-header' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.header}} />
        <div className='my-content'>Hello world</div>
        <div className='my-footer' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.footer}} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then all you would have to return from your server would be an object like this:

```
{
  header: '<div>This is my header content</div>',
  footer: '<div>This is my footer content</div>'
}
```

Here is some more information on dangerouslySetInnerHTML:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

You could also do this with server side rendering but I think that is too complicated for what you want to do with this. However here are some links if you need/want them:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html